# How can I recursively search for directory names with a particular string where the string is only part of the directory name

Tags: grep

How can I recursively search for directory names with a particular string where the string is only part of the directory name?

For example:
the directory name is "8.0.3-99966_en", but I want to recursively search for directories with the string "99966".

Answer (score 195):

You can use the `find` command:

```
find YOUR_STARTING_DIRECTORY -type d -name "*99966*" -print
```

Example:

```
find ~ -type d -name "*99966*" -print
```

should find all directories (`-type d`) starting from your home directory (`~`)that have their names containing the string "99966" (`-name "*99966*"`) and output them (`-print`).

Comment: How can I exclude a certain directory from the search? I need to search / but I get tons of /proc results which I do not care about.

Comment: @Kuzuch (after a while!): you can use negative grep, piping the sinf search into a commend like:  find <whatever> | grep -v "/proc" which will filter out all lines *containing* the search string.

Comment: Ho Ho Ho! I've found this useful today. Thanks, my friend. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: Is there a way to limit depth? this can save hours

Answer (score 41):

To avoid all of the "Permission denied" results, you can use:

```
find / -type d -name "*99966*" -print 2>/dev/null
```

See this article on [null device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) and this one on [standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) for more info.

Comment: works for me :) ~

Answer (score 15):

You can pipe the output to `grep` to have it highlight the directory name
Something like

```
find / -type d | grep "directory name"
```

The `/` indicates to search the whole computer

Comment: @Zanna you are right, I've edited the answer. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to do this is to use `find | egrep string`.   If there are too many hits, then use the `-type d` flag for find.   Run the command at the start of the directory tree you want to search, or you will have to supply the directory as an argument to `find` as well.

Another way to do this is to use `ls -laR | egrep ^d`.

And the `locate` command also comes in handy: `locate string`